# Are Rego function calls memoized?

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have defined a function that is not idempotent; it can return different results for the same inputs. Does Rego memoize the result of the function *on each query*? In other words, given the following policy:

```
val := myFunc(...) # Returns an object with "a" and "b" fields.

foo {
    val.a
}

bar {
    val.b
}
```

Rules `foo` and `bar` would operate on the same `val` which resulted from a single call to `myFunc`. Does Rego guarantee this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for `http.send`, I don't think there are any builtins that would allow you to return different data provided the same input. I'd be curious to find out though! :)

To answer your question, a rule/function is cached in the scope of a single query, so multiple calls to the same rule/function won't be re-evaluated. The `http.send` builtin additionally allows you to cache results *across* queries, which can be very useful when requesting data which is rarely updated.

Speaking of `http.send`, it's a pretty useful builtin to test things like this. Just fire up a local webserver, e.g. `python3 -m http.server` and then have a policy that queries that:

```
package policy

my_func(x) {
    http.send({
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000",
    })
}

boo := my_func("x")
foo := my_func("x")
```

Then evaluate the policy:

```bash
opa eval -f pretty -d policy.rego data.policy
{
  "boo": true,
  "foo": true
}
```

Checking the logs of the web server, you'll see that only one request was sent despite two rules calling the `my_func` function:

```bash
::1 - - [29/Jun/2022 19:27:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Just FYI, my function is calling http.send under the covers. The HTTP endpoint is non-idempotent, so the function is as well.

Comment: If you'd really want different outcomes then, you'd have to split it out into two separate functions or rules making the call.